# IHTTPModule performance hit?

Tags: asp.net, performance, ihttpmodule

I'm implementing an IHttpModule as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686073/ensure-page-is-only-accessed-via-ssl/686650#686650).  Since we're examining every request, I'm worried there may be a performance hit.  Has anyone run into performance issues implementing IHttpModules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what it's doing...there are so many events in the pipeline that you probably don't know about it's really a "drop in the bucket" situation overall.

If it's does a lot of heavy stuff, it'll have an impact (it'd have to be *real* heavy...or scale across a *lot* of hits).  If it's something small/light...you won't notice it's there.